# Installing dvipng package Error:(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

Tags: texlive

After installing Tex Live with the downloaded zip, I am trying to install the package dvipng(needed to use Latex in Anki), but I am getting this error:

```
victor@victor-GL552VW:~$ sudo tlmgr install dvipng
[sudo] contraseña para victor: 
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/victor/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/victor/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.
```

What can I Do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With `downloaded zip` you mean the `install-tl.X.tar.gz` file? Are you sure that TL is really installed or there is no conflict with some older installation of TL? Apparently you did not a full install procedure otherwise you would have `dvipng` already at your system.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I think the manual installation finished ok, but how can I verify if there is an older installation of TL?

Comment: Perhaps you have a TL installation by distribution packages of debian? What does `which pdflatex` say, or `pdflatex -v`? One standard path for installation is /usr/local/texlive

Comment: First: /usr/bin/pdflatex
Second: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0

Comment: Looks like an old version of TL and you're using the debian package version of TL .... output for TL 2018 is `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)` etc. (updated this morning). You should use apt-get etc. to kick the out the debian TL packages and install again the version from the `.zip` file. Otherwise you're in trouble with wrong paths and file versions

Comment: Right, the zip was downloaded this morning, that's the version of the zip I installed. So, what should I do?

Comment: See my comment about 36min ago... remove the Debian TL packages with your Linux distribution package manager

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I missed that sentence first time I read it. I will try that, thanks for all